# Secure DNS, NAT, DSNMASQ, and local addresses

Tags: networking, router, dns, nat

My home network consists of an ISP supplied router, a Raspberry PI providing DHCP, DNS with dnsmasq, including local addresses behind NAT. Some weeks ago, I noticed that when I tried to connect to my internal web server using its name (nginx, gunicorn, django), I ended up on my router's admin page. Using the same client computer, I tried ping to the address which took me where it was supposed to.

After some hair pulling and much googling, and after trying Firefox instead of Chrome, which worked fine, I found out about "Secure DNS", which appears to use an external DNS instead of the one that the client system (as was passed by dhcp) was set to. My dchp server sets all clients to my local dnsmasq, with 8.8.8.8 as a backup. Dnsmasq uses 8.8.8.8, and 8.8.8.4.

By turning secure dns off, it once again works as expected.

My question is: Is there some way to have secure dns but retain my local dns for serving local addresses and perhaps caching?

A secondary question is should I care about having secure dns?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Secure DNS" is DNS-over-TLS, or perhaps DNS-over-HTTPS (aka DoT and DoH), together with using a DNS service that your browser partners with (like Cloudflare DNS).

The original goal of browsers using DoT/DoH is mainly to protect one of the last remaining plaintext services from a possibly untrusted local network (like HTTPS has already been doing for everything else). So it's by design incompatible with local caching done *by* the local network. It *could* be compatible with local domain names if they're distinguishable (e.g. I would *expect* the browser to use local DNS for the domain that you're advertising via DHCP ”Domain Suffix"), but that's up to the client implementation and I'm actually not sure whether browsers bother.

However, in practice it depends on your own risk assessment. If you're on a network that *is* trusted, then you might not necessarily need DoT end-to-end – instead you could have *your dnsmasq* use a DoT server as its upstream. This allows local domains but still protects external queries against e.g. ISP-level interception, which some ISPs are known to do (especially when it comes to legally imposed blocking and such).

The DNS service you're currently using (8.8.8.8) supports both DoT and DoH connections. Unfortunately I don't think dnsmasq speaks TLS though, so to do that you'd actually need something like Unbound or another DoT/DoH capable proxy.

(The level of security and/or privacy of DoT vs DoH is identical; both use the same TLS in the same way. The latter only has a negative association with Big Large CDNs because they prefer HTTP-based protocols and thus they market DoH more, while DoT has more of an association with smaller artisanal services, but in reality pretty much all services provide both protocols.)

Comment: Thank you. I think my main concern is going to be making sure I turn it back on if I'm travelling and using open wifi networks where that DNS exploit is more likely to occur.  Re-enabling is easy to do, but also easy to forget. Thanks for your answer.